# MongoDB aggregation, combining 2 arrays in round-robin fashion

Tags: mongodb

I have data in a MongoDB collection that looks something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "type": "big",
    "fields": [11, 12, 13],
    "items": [21, 22, 23]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "type": "small",
    "fields": [14, 15],
    "items": [24, 25]
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "type": "small",
    "fields": [],
    "items": [41, 42]
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "type": "small",
    "fields": [31, 32, 33],
    "items": []
  }
]
```

I have been tasked with returning data according to a procedure like this:

> For each document in the collection, obtain 1 value from its `fields` (if there are any), and 1 value its `items` (if there are any). Concatenate all of the results in a single array.

One might summarize this as selecting data in "round robin" fashion from two arrays held in each document.

How would I achieve this in a MongoDB aggregation query? This logic is not hard to implement in the client that connects to the Mongo server, but I would like to let Mongo take care of pagination (with `$skip` and `$limit`). I am using MongoDB 4.4.

The resulting data would look something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "value": 11,
    "type": "field",
    "fromId": 1
  },
  {
    "value": 21,
    "type": "item",
    "fromId": 1
  },
  {
    "value": 14,
    "type": "field",
    "fromId": 2
  },
  {
    "value": 24,
    "type": "item",
    "fromId": 2
  },
  {
    "value": 41,
    "type": "item",
    "fromId": 3
  },
  {
    "value": 31,
    "type": "field",
    "fromId": 4
  },
]
```

Comment: So is always the first element of those arrays that you grab or does it have have to be random?

Comment: In this case it's the first element, but I think the current logic is not finalized and it might be randomized in the future. The algorithm itself is somewhat underspecified; I'm open to a variety of solutions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right; this should be a workable pipe. To implement a random functionality, you would simply adjust the index passed to $arrayElemAt

https://mongoplayground.net/p/PPXV6fTSwHP

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
     types: [
      {type: "field", values: "$fields"},
      {type: "item", values: "$items"}
    ]
  }},
  {$unwind: '$types'},
  {$project: {
    _id: 0,
    value: {$arrayElemAt: ['$types.values', 0]},
    type: '$types.type',
    fromId: '$_id'
  }},
  {$match: {
    value: {$exists: true}
  }}
])
```

Randomizing would look something like this:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/qi1Ud53J6yv

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
     types: [
      {type: "field", values: "$fields"},
      {type: "item", values: "$items"}
    ]
  }},
  {$unwind: '$types'},
  {$project: {
    _id: 0,
    value: {$arrayElemAt: [
      '$types.values',
      {$floor: {$multiply: [{$rand: {}}, {$size: '$types.values'}]}}
    ]},
    type: '$types.type',
    fromId: '$_id'
  }},
  {$match: {
    value: {$exists: true}
  }}
])
```

Comment: I'm still new to MongoDB. What does the syntax `{types: [ a , b ]}` do? Does it just create a 2-element array (containing `a` and `b`) in the projection?

Comment: Yes exactly. We're essentially turning each single document into two documents, one for each type, by using that projection and then $unwinding the array it creates.